# Image url from S3 is not working in Django template

Tags: django, amazon-s3

My django back-end and website is hosted in heroku. My media files are hosted in Amazon S3. I have no issue with uploading image to S3. But when I try to embed image url from S3 into img tag, then I have problem. It does not show image.

```
<img src="{{ taxi.user_photo.url }}" alt="Photo of user">
```

here is the url that is returned: https://elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-865036748267.s3.amazonaws.com/media/user_photo/default_taksist.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA4S2BVIXV43WWVZG4&Signature=En2f5F65B61oaYexN2HIIcWIgME%3D&Expires=1631531071

In this link there are KeyId and Signature, I have no idea why it is like that.

And, here is my S3 bucket policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-865036748267/*"
    }
]
```

}

I checked other answers in stackoverflow, they did not help much.

Base point is that I have a url but that is not working somehow.

Any help of yours is appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In your bucket settings uncheck blocking all the public access
2. Generate permissions

---

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1631681912120",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
{
  "Sid": "Stmt1631681911100",
  "Action": [
    "s3:GetObject"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your_bucket_name/*",
  "Principal": "*"
}
]
}
```

3. settings.py

---

```
AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'secret_key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY  = 'secret_access_key'
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "your_bucket_region"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'your_bucket_name'

AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False # it will remove the authentication info from the url

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

[django-storage documentation](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html)